# List of CC for email purposes not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I have an `EmailFormModel` class.

```
public class EmailFormModel
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Your Name:")]
    public string FromName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Your Email:")]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "To Email:")]
    public string ToEmail { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> CCEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public EmailFormModel()
    {
        CCEmail = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

}
```

Now I need this email to have multiple CC recipients, hence why I made the property `CCEmail` a type of `List`.  In my `HttpGet` method I am populating the list which is correctly working.  In my `HttpPost` I am doing this:

```
foreach(var item in model.CCEmail)
{
    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(item.Text));
}
```

Now, in my View... what can I do to display these email addresses.. so that when I hit Submit they will be submitted as email addresses?

Currently in my View I have this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CCEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.CCEmail,null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CCEmail)
        </div>
</div>
```

Is there another/better way to display the email addresses rather than `ListBoxFor`?

But when I select the email addresses.. and then hit Submit, I get an error message:

> The value 'John.Doe@test.com,Test.User1@test.com' is invalid.

Those aren't the real email addresses.. the ones that I am using are valid.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I have found an alternative solution, I am still looking for a cleaner solution.  Here is what I have done.

I changed the `CCEmail` property to a `List<string>`.

So, in the `HttpPost` method I changed the foreach loop to this syntax:

```
foreach(var item in model.CCEmail)
{
    message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(item));
}
```

Then in my view, I did this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach(var item in Model.CCEmail)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CCEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("CCEmail", item, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true  } )
            </div>
    }  
</div>
```

Even though this creates 2 separate textboxes, it still submits as 2 separate email addresses instead of both of them combined as what I think the error in my OP was.

Again, if you know of a simpler/cleaner solution, please post!